# Is there a automation framework for gtk# applications?

Tags: c#, .net, testing, mono, automation

Is there a automation framework for gtk# applications like [white](http://white.codeplex.com/) or [NUnitForms](http://nunitforms.sourceforge.net/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [Strongwind](http://medsphere.org/community/project/strongwind), which uses the GTK accessibility interfaces (note that these only work on Linux). Although it's Python, it *was* written for testing a GTK# app, and presumably you could implement something similar directly in C# using [AT-SPI#](http://github.com/mono/at-spi-sharp).

Comment: I have already been looking at strongwind. It's pretty powerful and straitforward. But I will have a look at AT-SPI#. Maybe it allows for portable acceptance tests... (portable as in "runs anwhere where mono is available")

Comment: Unfortunately AFAIK the actual GTK+ accessibility infrastructure - ATK, AT-SPI - only works fully on Linux/Unix :/ (http://www.mail-archive.com/gtk-list@gnome.org/msg24604.html)

Comment: FYI MonoDevelop has some simple UI tests using an external controller that uses remoting to connect to a MD instance and make direct API calls. It's more tightly coupled than most UI tests, but it is portable - http://github.com/mono/monodevelop/tree/master/main/tests/UserInterfaceTests/